# Read all linux partitions with Java

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee

I found this Java code which is used to get all partitions in Linux.

```
public class Partitions
{
    // output
    // [8, 0, 312571224, sda, 8, 1, 716800, sda1, 8, 2, 5120000, sda2, 8, 3, 306733056, sda3]
    public static final String partitionsPath = "/proc/partitions";
    public static final String EMPTY = "";
    public static final String SPACE = " ";
    public static final String LINE_SEPARATOR = "line.separator";

    public ArrayList<String> gatherPartitionUsage()
    {
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] tempData = null;
        String[] tempFile = null;

        tempFile = getContents(partitionsPath).split(System.getProperty(LINE_SEPARATOR));

        //parse the disk partitions
        for (int i = 2; i < tempFile.length; i++)
        {
            tempData = tempFile[i].split(SPACE);
            data.addAll(Arrays.asList(tempData));
            data.removeAll(Collections.singleton(EMPTY));
        }
        return data;
    }

    static private synchronized String getContents(String path)
    {
        //...checks on aFile are elided
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            //use buffering, reading one line at a time
            //FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
            try
            {
                String line = null; //not declared within while loop
                /*
                 * readLine is a bit quirky : it returns the content of a line
                 * MINUS the newline. it returns null only for the END of the
                 * stream. it returns an empty String if two newlines appear in
                 * a row.
                 */
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    contents.append(line);
                    contents.append(System.getProperty(LINE_SEPARATOR));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                input.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }

        return contents.toString();
    }

    /*
     * Create a list with the partitions name to be used to find their
     * statistics in /proc/diskstats file
     */
    private ArrayList<String> getPartitionNames(ArrayList<String> data)
    {
        ArrayList<String> partitionsName = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : data)
        {
            if (!tryParseInt(string))
            {
                partitionsName.add(string);
            }
        }
        return partitionsName;
    }

    /**
     * Try to parse a string to a integer.
     *
     * @param value
     * @return True if the string can be converted, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean tryParseInt(String value)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(value);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            //  Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This should be the output

[8, 0, 312571224, sda, 8, 1, 716800, sda1, 8, 2, 5120000, sda2, 8, 3, 306733056, sda3]

Can tell me this correct? Looks like it's working for now. Also how I can keep the returned result in a Java Map?

Comment: when you ran the program what was the output or are you asking us to run this for you?

Comment: Well, it is highly system sepcific. You need to be aware that it might not work on all systems (proc not mounted, chroot or container isolation). Besides partitions might be less usefull if you are interested in potential or existing mount points (think LVM and others). If you are more interested about the existing mounted filesystems, go for /proc/mounts or even `FileSystems.getDefault().getFilestores()`

Comment: I get the same result similar to the post. Can you run the code and see the result?

Comment: @eckes can you how me some code examples?

Comment: @user1285928 it might be a good idea to tell us what you are interested in, for what purpose. If you want to write a front-end for partition manipulation maybe forking "lsblk" and reading its output is better.

Comment: I just want to print all Linux partitions as a pie chart - partitions name and partition size. To do this I need to get all partitions and sizes.

Comment: Are you sure "partition" is the right word? Files can be stored in disks or LUNs with no partitions or in volumes spanning multiple partitions (not to mention network storage). For most purposes the FileStore above is the most user visible incarnation of volumes.

Comment: Ok, I will use the word mounted shares.

Comment: Parsing output of `df` is better in that case (or use getFileStores()  :).